# Simple sorting example

Tags: react-data-grid

Is there a better explanation on how to implement sorting in React-Data-Grid?

The example on the website is utterly confusing.

https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/column-sorting

Nothing is explained, and the example deals with **initialRows** and the react utility funciton **useState**.

Why do I need to use **setRows** in the following example?

```
  onGridSort={(sortColumn, sortDirection) =>
    setRows(sortRows(initialRows, sortColumn, sortDirection))
  }
```

Where does this **setRows** object come from? Why is useState being used in this presentational component? What is it? Where does it come from?